# How to scrape data from a dynamic website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape data from https://bepick.net/#/game/default/nlotto_power But I am facing problems to get the live scores because it's not showing in the soup. [I want to scrape this columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmrcf.png)

Comment: Please show us what you're trying to do so we can help with specific problems, nobody will just write code for you. Also for dynamic website we recommend using selenium instead of request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this url to extract the data. data loaded via this url. take a look inspect google chrome network tab.

```
url ="https://bepick.net/api/get_pattern/nlotto_power/default/fd1/20?_=1606793203624"
r = requests.get(url)
mydata =r.json()
for data in mydata['list']:
    print(data["title"])
    print(data["round"])
```

Comment: I wanna learn more about google chrome network tab network. Where can i find it?

Comment: Open the url  https://bepick.net/#/game/default/nlotto_power, then click right button of mouse then click inspect and finally click on Network tab. Under the name header you will see the desire url.  please accept my answer. Thanks